# 95% confidence interval for an estimate average

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, variance, dataset

I have a single dataset - from that dataset I have used four methods ($i=1, 2, 3, 4$) to estimate a parameter ($u_i$) and to generate a 95% confidence interval. In other words, I know $V[u_i]$ but not $Cov[u_1, u_2]$ (or any of the other covariances). The four estimates are therefore not independent (because they rely on the same data source).

I need to average my four estimates. How do I generate a 95% confidence interval for the average estimate based on what I have (four estimates and four variances)?

Edit: Consider the following. A researcher goes out and collects data, but they know that there were some errors involved. There are a few different methods the researcher can use to correct for potential errors, but they don't know which method is correct. They want to use an average of the four correction methods. The raw data is summarized into two values, $p_1$ and $p_2$, which is used to calculate $u$ ($u=\frac{p_1-p_2}{1-p_2}$). They know the variance of $p_1$ and $p_2$ and thus can use the delta method to calculate the variance of $u$. Here's an example of the data and the resulting corrections (Sorry for picture format, I saw no way to create a table...):

[image]

Comment: Do the four methods estimate a different parameter?

Comment: The coexistence of these 4 methods only proofs there is no *holy grail* answer to the question how to compute a confidence interval.

Comment: Can you provide simple data & your estimation methods?

Comment: The four methods are estimating the same parameter and use the same formulas, but they use different subsets of the same dataset. I'll try to come up with a simple version and edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you estimate all the corrections simultaneously like you would for Generalized Method of moments or a multivariate likelihood? If the $p$'s are based on some minimization/maximization criterion, you might be able to form a simultaneous system of equations.  Optimizing this would give you a complete covariance matrix for all the parameters and you would be able to use the Delta method for the average.  How do you calculate the $p$'s?

Comment: Each $p$ is a proportion, or the ratio of one group/subset of the data to the total data. Each correction subsets the data in a different way, so there's really no way to combine them in a likelihood sort of way.

Comment: An example of how each p is generated is this - let's say I want to know the proportion of red M&Ms in a bag. I can just count the red ones and divide by the total, which would be the raw value. But if I know that somebody's been eating out of the bag already, I need to correct in some way. Let's say one person told me they saw somebody only eating the red ones out of the bag - that would be one type of correction. But then another person told me they saw them eating only red and blue ones, so that would be another correction.

Comment: Perhaps a bootstrap then?  If your sample is large enough you may be able to simulate the statistic of interest.

Comment: I could try that, it just seems like such a waste when the rest of my variance estimates were computed analytically... Also the R code I have already takes quite some time to get through so I don't think bootstrapping would be very efficient.